# Limiting the results in Blade foreach loop

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Alright so I'm pretty new to Blade, and I did manage to get all the results that I asked for on my page. Now I want to show only 10 of the total items on my page and I seem to struggle with it, tried the array_slice without any success so far. Any suggestions?

Below the code I'm currently using

```
        {{--@foreach ($element['subs']->slice(0, 10) as $item)--}}

@foreach ($element['subs'] as $item)
        <div class="highlight {{ $element['class'] }}">
            <div class="el-inner-news">

                <div class="image-news">
                    <a href="{{ $item['news-item']['slug'] }}"> <img src="{{ $item['news-item']['image'] or "/assets/frontend/baywest/images/newsholder.png" }}" class="center-img" alt="{{ $item['news-item']['title'] }}" /> </a>
                </div>

                <div class="desc-news">
                    <div class="title-highlight">
                        <a href="{{ $item['news-item']['slug'] }}">{{ $item['news-item']['title'] }}</a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="text-highlight">
                        {!! $item['news-item']['textfield'] !!}
                    </div>

                    <div class="learn-more-news">
                        <a href="{{ $item['news-item']['slug'] }}">{{ $item['news-item']['read-more'] or "Learn more" }}  </a>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    @endforeach
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is `$element['subs']` an array or a collection?

Comment: Return 10 results from the controller, don`t try to cut it up in the view, that seems like bad practice.

Comment: @TimLewis I disagree. Maybe there's no way to do this in blade (and that's fine) but there's nothing wrong with been able to do this within a template (considering that I might want to use the same array in another part of the template but with a different loop count). This feature should be available at least for convenience.

Comment: @Gboyega Well, there's always a `@for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) ... @endfor` that can be used, or a foreach with a count (like the answer below). My comment was simply a statement on the strangeness of query for every result, sending those to the view but then only using 10... Just seems odd.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should limit the results in controller, but here's how you can accomplish this in a blade. Not pretty.

```
<?php $count = 0; ?>
@foreach ($element['subs'] as $item)
    <?php if($count == 10) break; ?>
    // Your code
    <?php $count++; ?>
@endforeach
```

Comment: I'm not using the controllers at the moment, I'm just putting it inside the front-end. It does work, so thanks for that! I will look into the controller things and keep learning. Cheers though!

Answer (score 60):

A cleaner way to do it could be this if it is a collection:

```
@foreach ($element['subs']->slice(0, 10) as $item)
 ...Code
@endforeach
```

another way for collections:

```
@foreach ($element['subs']->take(10) as $item)
 ...Code
@endforeach
```

or this if it is an array:

```
@foreach (array_slice($element['subs'], 0, 10) as $item)
 ...Code
@endforeach
```

Comment: This is what makes a good programmer an experts :)) cleaner code == god saves a kitty :)

Comment: Nice it is very clean and understanding Thanks you

Answer (score 9):

Late, but to extend [Pawel Bieszczad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33393558/6612932) in laravel 5.4 you can use the `index` property of the [loop variable](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#the-loop-variable):

```
@foreach ($element['subs'] as $item)
    @if($loop->index < 10)
        // Your code
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 8):

As far as I know the easiest way to do this is by using the `take(N)` function, where **N** stands for the number of loops.

```
@foreach($element->take(5) as $item)
  ..your code
@endforeach
```

Example

```
@foreach($posts->take(5) as $post)
  {{ $post->message }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank a lot. This is the best answer

Answer (score 7):

Since [Laravel 5.3](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#loops) there is a blade way to do this by using the Loop variable and the break directive:

```
@foreach ($element['subs'] as $item)

  @if($loop->iteration > 10)

    @break

  @endif

  {{-- Your loop code here --}}

@endforeach
```

Comment: Where does $loop come from?

Comment: It is defined by blade. More info at https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade#the-loop-variable

Answer (score 4):

**Take method help you**

```
 <div class="col-md-4" style="margin-top:40px; margin-bottom:40px">
   @foreach($reviews->take(10) as $review)
      <div  class="carousel-cell">
           {{ $review->id }}
      </div>
   @endforeach
</div>
```

**Second Way**

```
<div class="col-md-4" style="margin-top:40px; margin-bottom:40px">
   @foreach($reviews as $count => $review)
    @if($count< 10)
      <div  class="carousel-cell">
           {{ $review->id }}
      </div>
    @endif
   @endforeach
</div>
```