# foreach limit loop break blade laravel

Tags: php, laravel, controller, laravel-blade

My Table: 'blog'

```
  id  |   cat  |  title
---------------------------
   1  |   3,4  |  Post 01    X
   2  |   1,2  |  Post 02
   3  |   4,2  |  Post 03    X
   4  |   3,2  |  Post 04
   5  |   1,1  |  Post 05
   6  |   3,1  |  Post 06
   7  |   3,2  |  Post 07
   8  |   3,4  |  Post 08    X
   9  |   1,4  |  Post 09    X
  10  |   2,4  |  Post 10    X
  11  |   4,6  |  Post 11    X
  12  |   4,7  |  Post 12    X
  13  |   4,1  |  Post 13    X
  14  |   7,4  |  Post 14    X
  15  |   4,2  |  Post 15    X
```

My Route: **routes/web.php**

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\Frontend\CategoryController

Route::get('/cat',[CategoryController::class,'CAT']);
```

My Controller: **app/Http/Controllers/Frontend/CategoryController.php**

```
<?php 
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Frontend;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    public function CAT(){
        $cats = DB::table('blog')->orderBy('id','DESC')->get();
        $cat_select = '4';
        $data = array( 'cats' => $cats, 'cat_select' => $cat_select, );
        return view('frontend.category', $data );
    }
}
```

My Blade: **resources/views/frontend/category.blade.php**

```
@foreach($cats->take(5) as $row)
    @php
        $data = $row->cat;
        $sep_cat = explode(',' , $data);
    @endphp
    @foreach ($sep_cat as $cat)
         @if ( $cat == $cat_select )
            {{$row->id}} |  {{$row->title}}
        @endif
    @endforeach 
@endforeach
```

Output:

```
1  |  Post 01
3  |  Post 03
```

But i want to display the output as follows: **( $cat_select = '4' and Limit: 5 )**

```
1  |  Post 01
3  |  Post 03
8  |  Post 08
9  |  Post 09
10 |  Post 10
```

I checked this link below but it does not display correctly:
[Limiting the results in Blade foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33393376/limiting-the-results-in-blade-foreach-loop)

How do I change the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `foreach loop` use laravel query to get 5 record with `cat_select = 4` using `whereRaw` query

```
$cats = DB::table('blog')->whereRaw("find_in_set('4',cat)")->limit(5)->get();

@foreach($cats as $row)
    {{$row->id}} |  {{$row->title}}    
@endforeach
```

so decrease the code and get faster output.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$cats->take(5)` takes the first 5 results (so id 1 to 5. 8, 9 and then aren't part of that selection). You can use a counter that you update with each post, and then break after 5:

```
@php $i = 0; @endphp
@foreach($cats as $row)
    @if (in_array($cat_select, explode(',' , $row->cat)))
        {{$row->id}} |  {{$row->title}}
        @php $i++; @endphp
        @if($i == 5) @break @endif
    @endif
@endforeach
```

(I've also cleaned up your blade a bit)

Comment: You can remove `$i` and use `$loop->index`. This will automatically add 1 every loop.

Comment: @GertB. They don't need the index of the loop itself, the loop needs to break if the internal condition is met 5 times, which can be after 8, 10 or 100 loops.

Comment: Correct, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is set query with your condition first.
do your  app/Http/Controllers/Frontend/CategoryController.php:

```
<?php 
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Frontend;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    public function CAT(){
        $cat_select = '4';
        $cats = DB::table('blog')->where('cat', 'like', "$cat_select,%")
                 ->orWhere('cat', 'like', "%,$cat_select")
                 ->orWhere('cat', 'like', "%,$cat_select,%")
                 ->orderBy('id','DESC')->get();
        
        $data = array( 'cats' => $cats, 'cat_select' => $cat_select, );
        return view('frontend.category', $data );
    }
}
```

But I recommend you to use json in the table:

```
  id  |   cat  |  title
---------------------------
   1  |   [3,4]  |  Post 01    X
   2  |   [1,2]  |  Post 02
   3  |   [4,2]  |  Post 03    X
```

so your query will change to this:

```
        $cats = DB::table('blog')->whereJsonContains('cat', $cat_select)
                 ->orderBy('id','DESC')->get();
```

and resources/views/frontend/category.blade.php will be:

```
@foreach($cats as $row)
    {{$row->id}} |  {{$row->title}}
@endforeach
```