# limit find_in_set whereRaw foreach laravel

Tags: laravel, foreach, controller, laravel-blade

My Table: 'home'

```
  id  | selected 
-------------------
   1  |   3     
   2  |   5 
   3  |   6  
   4  |   7 
   5  |   9
```

My Table: 'blog'

```
  id  |   cat  |  title
---------------------------
   1  |   3,4  |  Post 01    
   2  |   1,2  |  Post 02
   3  |   4,2  |  Post 03    
   4  |   3,2  |  Post 04
   5  |   1,1  |  Post 05
   6  |   3,1  |  Post 06
   7  |   3,2  |  Post 07
   8  |   3,5  |  Post 08    
   9  |   1,4  |  Post 09    
  10  |   2,4  |  Post 10    
  11  |   4,6  |  Post 11    
  12  |   9,7  |  Post 12    
  13  |   4,3  |  Post 13    
  14  |   7,4  |  Post 14    
  15  |   4,3  |  Post 15
```

My Route: routes/web.php

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\Frontend\HomeController
Route::get('/home',[CategoryController::class,'Home']);
```

My Controller: app/Http/Controllers/Frontend/HomeController.php

```
<?php 
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Frontend;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    public function Home(){
        $home = DB::table('home')->whereRaw("find_in_set(?,selected)")->limit(4)->get();
        $blog = DB::table('blog')->limit(3)->get();
        $data = array( 'home' => $home, 'blog' => $blog );
        return view('frontend.home', $data );
    }
}
```

My Blade: resources/views/frontend/category.blade.php

```
@foreach($home as $row_home)
    {{$row_home->id}} |
    @php $i = 0; $selected = $row_home->selected; @endphp 
    @foreach($blog as $row_blog)
        @if (in_array( $selected , explode(',' , $row_blog->cat)))
                {{$row_blog->title}} ,
            @php $i++; @endphp
            @if($i == 5) @break @endif
        @endif
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Output:

```
3  |   Post 01 ,
5  |   
6  |   
7  |
```

But i want to display the output as follows:

```
3  |   Post 01 , Post 04 , Post 06
5  |   Post 08 , 
6  |   Post 11 , 
7  |   Post 12 , Post 14
```

I checked this link below but it does not display correctly:
[foreach limit loop break blade laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71762073/foreach-limit-loop-break-blade-laravel)

How do I change the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@foreach($home as $row_home)
    {{$row_home->id}}
    @php $i = 0; $selected = $row_home->selected; @endphp 
    @foreach($blog as $row_blog)
        @if (in_array( $selected , explode(';' , $row_blog->cat)))
                {{$row_blog->title}} ,
            @php $i++; @endphp
            @if($i == 5) @break @endif
         @break
        @endif
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```